# Unclear concepts

Tags: c#, debugging, logic

```
public static List<int> dynamicArray(int n, List<List<int>> qu)
        {
            List<int> ls1 = new List<int>();
            int lastAnswer = 0;
            foreach (List<int> ls in qu)
            {
                int index = (ls[1] ^ lastAnswer) % n;

                if (ls[0] == 1)
                {
                    List<int> s1111 = qu[index];

                    s1111.Add(ls[2]);
                }
                else
                {
                    List<int> s1111 = qu[index];

                    int ind = ls[2] % s1111.Count;
                    lastAnswer = s1111[ind];
                    ls1.Add(lastAnswer);

                }
            }
            return ls1;
        }
```

While debugging I found out that qu list values are changing I am very confused why that is happening since nowhere I am changing the value of qu.

Sorry in advance if the question is silly but still I need to clear my doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this:

```
List<int> s1111 = qu[index];
```

...you're not getting a copy (or clone) of `qu[index]`, you're getting a reference to it.

So this:

`s1111.Add(ls[2]);`

...is the same as if you did this:

`qu[index].Add(ls[2]);`

If you want to operate on a clone, and leave `qu` intact, you could do this:

```
List<int> s1111 = qu[index].ToList();
```

Or this:

```
List<int> s1111 = new List<int>(qu[index]);
```

...but understand that both of these will work as expected for a `List<T>` of values types (such as `int`). If you were working with reference type elements, then changes to properties of the elements in `s1111` would be reflected in the elements of `qu[index]` because again, each element is just a reference to the original. Just something to keep in mind as you move forward.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.